# Stop activityIndicator in Embedded TableView Cell Upon Return From Detail ViewController

Tags: ios

I have a viewController that has a container view.  In the container view I have a tableView that contains static cells.  Each cell has a disclosure indicator.  This was all created in IB.  The parent viewController is embedded in a navigationController.

Each cell pushes a new view controller which loads a mapView. Each map parses and loads a .kml file.  The .kml files are huge and take up to a minute (or more) to load.

I placed an activityIndicator in the accessory view of each cell using the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView =
[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[activityView startAnimating];
[cell setAccessoryView:activityView];

[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];}
```

This appears to work as expected.

After viewing the map I touch the "back" button provided by the navigationController and pop the map off the stack.  My embedded tableView is visible again, with the activity indicator still spinning.  I can't get it to stop.

My best attempt was in the implementation file of my tableView:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[[self tableView] reloadData];}
```

But that didn't work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `reloadData` in the table view controller's `viewWillAppear` would work as long as in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, you're setting the state for `UIActivityIndicatorView` by calling it's `stopAnimating` method (or simply remove it from the view) for any cell that shouldn't be spinning.

You'll need to reference the activity indicator via the `accesstoryView` property.

In your data, you could store a property that indicates whether the indicator should still be spinning for that map and set it appropriately.

Another method would be to stop the activity indicator in `prepareForSegue`, just prior to showing the map view.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  It seems that when I add a stopAnimating method to my cellForRowAtIndexPath method my activityIndicator stops working altogether. It's like I'm starting and stopping it at the same time.  As for storing a property on my data, I don't have any data.  This whole problem seems to be based upon the fact that I'm not using prototype cells and populating them with an NSArray.  But, I just can't do that.  Each cell is static and leads to a map, each with such different properties that I can't make one DetailViewController.

Comment: @bronyaur, basically, you need to store state for the spinning activity for each row. You refer to that state in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Set that state in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, and turn it off in your `viewWillAppear` or some other time such as `prepareForSegue`. Even if they're static cells, you still need to store state for the rows.

Comment: Okay that makes sense.  I don't have a clue how I will do that but I'll figure it out.  Thanks.